# Where do I set the domain for my Django Sites framework site, when I only have one?

Tags: django, django-sites

I have a Django project for a simple blog/forum website I’m building.

I’m using the [syndication feed framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/), which seems to generate the URLs for items in the feed using the domain of the current site from [the Sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/).

I was previously unaware of the Sites framework. My project isn’t going to be used for multiple sites, just one.

What I want to do is set the `domain` property of the current site. Where in my Django project should I do that? Somewhere in /settings.py?

Comment: Ah: kind of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536123/where-do-i-set-my-site-url-in-django-settings

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If I understand correctly, Sites framework data is stored in the database, so if I want to store this permanently, I guess it’s appropriate in an [`initial_data` fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

I fired up the Django shell, and did the following:

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> one = Site.objects.all()[0]
>>> one.domain = 'myveryspecialdomain.com'
>>> one.name = 'My Special Site Name'
>>> one.save()
```

I then grabbed just this data at the command line:

```
python manage.py dumpdata sites
```

And pasted it into my pre-existing `initial_data` fixture.

Comment: One correction -- Site.domain should just be the domain name, not a URL. E.g. `example.com`, not `http://example.com/`

Comment: @PaulBissex: ah, thank you — I’ve updated the code example accordingly.

Comment: I need to restart my apache to make the update works. ```# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart```

Comment: Is there no better way to define this in the settings or so?

Comment: I get an error messagedjango.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Answer (score 20):

The other answers suggest to manually update the site in the admin, shell, or your DB. That's a bad idea—it should be automatic.

You can create a migration that'll do this automatically when you run your migrations, so you can be assured it's always applied (such as when you deploy to production). [This is also recommended in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework), but it doesn't list instructions.

First, run `./manage.py makemigrations --empty --name UPDATE_SITE_NAME myapp` to create an empty migration. Then add the following code:

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.conf import settings


def update_site_name(apps, schema_editor):
    SiteModel = apps.get_model('sites', 'Site')
    domain = 'mydomain.com'

    SiteModel.objects.update_or_create(
        pk=settings.SITE_ID,
        defaults={'domain': domain,
                  'name': domain}
    )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # Make sure the dependency that was here by default is also included here
        ('sites', '0002_alter_domain_unique'), # Required to reference `sites` in `apps.get_model()`
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(update_site_name),
    ]
```

Make sure you've set `SITE_ID` in your settings. Then run `./manage.py migrate` to apply the changes :)

Comment: To perform such a migration without having to create a purpose built app see [Thom Wiggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26947339) answer.

Comment: This answer is nearly perfect. I had to do a bit of work to understand what the above file was. It is a migration file, created by the "makemigrations" command. Edit that file as shown and run migrate etc.

Comment: What is " ('sites', '0002_alter_domain_unique')" doing?

Comment: @Alexander sorry I can't remember, this was a long time ago. IIRC it was something created by Django. Someone else here may know what it is.

Comment: What is the correct way to use this migration in multiple environments where each domain name is different? Is it OK that migrations read env vars or ?

Comment: @Alexander it's just a schema change. Here, it makes sure that the db schema for the sites framework exists.

@oglop: if you need to create different `site` objects you could have some issues with auto-increment id (see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15573)

Answer (score 9):

You can change it using django admin site.

Just go to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sites/`

Comment: admin/sites does not exist

Comment: @Sören Try with `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` and search for the sites section. I did this on django 2.0.1, maybe it changed on new versions and is no longer called sites.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the only answer that helped among all the answers on the internet.

Answer (score 7):

For those who are struggling to find "Sites" section on Django's admin page, for newer Django versions you need to enable the optional **Sites Framework** like so:

On your **settings.py** file, add this to your "INSTALLED_APPS":

```
'django.contrib.sites'
```

Then specify an ID for the default site (since it's probably your first site to be specified, you can use ID 1):

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

Run your migrations and check if the "Sites" section is available on your Django's admin page.

More details at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

Answer (score 5):

You can modify the Site entry in your database manually. Navigate to the table called '**django_site**'. Then, you should only see one entry (row). You'll want to modify the field (column) named '**domain**'.